# How to convert text files in a folder into a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to write a script to take a bunch of text files in a folder (which are all in the same format) and output them to a csv file. Each file has the same "header" information. I have been able to get information in a more easily usable format (removing the first and last lines, which aren't needed), but am having some trouble after that.

Here is the beginning of the text file, though there will be more than just these 7 lines, there will be a total of 36 lines per file:

```
TYPE       VOID
DOB        20200131
DATE       20200131
TIME       21:19:42
TERMINAL   3
ORGTERM    2
EMPLOYEE   1234 John Doe
```

And here is what I have so far, though I know that it doesn't work:

```
$currentdir = '.\'
$results = @()
$outputfilename = 'data.csv'

foreach ($req in Get-ChildItem($currentdir)) {

(Get-Content $req)[1..((Get-Content $req).count - 2)] | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $header = $_[0] -split '`t'
        $data = $_[1] -split '`t'
        $results = $header, $data
    }  
}
```

The final product would look something like this:

```
       A               B            C            D          E            F             G
1     TYPE            DOB          DATE         TIME     TERMINAL     ORGTERM       EMPLOYEE
2     VOID          20200131     20200131     21:19:42      3            2          1234 John Doe
3     AUTHORIZE     20200131     20200131     23:29:22      2                       4678 Jane Doe
```

Full sample of VOID file:

```
BEGIN
TYPE       VOID
DOB        20200131
DATE       20200131
TIME       21:19:42
TERMINAL   3
ORGTERM    2
EMPLOYEE   1234 Jane Doe
TABLE      TBL 101
CHECK      20030
PAYMENT    20029
AUTHAMT    20.68
BATCHAMT   20.68
CARDTYPE   MASTERCARD
CARDMASK   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
EXP        0423
REF        482
STANDALONE YES
PINDEX     1
APPROVEAMT 20.68
LOGTIME    21:07:01
FOHFEATS   10000000000000000000000000000000
TERMCAPS   00000000000000000000000000000000
FOHVERSION 15.1.34.2.97
ACTIONCODE 000
LASTSEND   1580585993
ORIGDATE   20200131
ORIGTIME   21:02:11
ORIGTYPE   AUTHORIZE
ORIGREF    482
ORGREFTIME 21:02:11
TENDER_NUM 12
CRCY       840
VPD        Sequence #: 107
REVID      2
REVNAME    712 Bar
END
```

Sample AUTHORIZE file:

```
BEGIN
TYPE       AUTHORIZE
DOB        20200131
DATE       20200131
TIME       23:29:22
TERMINAL   2
EMPLOYEE   1234 Jane Doe
TABLE      Table 121
CHECK      20045
PAYMENT    20038
AUTHAMT    72.42
BATCHAMT   72.42
CARDTYPE   VISA
CARDMASK   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
EXP        0124
REF        485900
STANDALONE YES
PINDEX     1
LOGTIME    23:29:22
FOHFEATS   10000000000000000000000000000000
TERMCAPS   00000000000000000000000000000000
FOHVERSION 15.1.34.2.97
LASTSEND   1580586235
TENDER_NUM 13
CRCY       840
REVID      1
REVNAME    712 Restaurant
COMMERROR  TRUE
END
```

Sample adjust file:

```
BEGIN
TYPE       ADJUST
DOB        20200131
DATE       20200131
TIME       22:18:27
TERMINAL   8
ORGTERM    8
EMPLOYEE   789 Judy Garland
TABLE      BAR GUEST
CHECK      80161
PAYMENT    80036
BATCHAMT   30.43
BATCHTIP   6
CARDTYPE   MASTERCARD
CARDMASK   XXXXXXXXXXXX8699
{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
EXP        0323
REF        1504602
STANDALONE YES
PINDEX     1
LOGTIME    22:18:27
FOHFEATS   10000000000000000000000000000000
TERMCAPS   00000000000000000000000000000000
FOHVERSION 15.1.34.2.97
LASTSEND   1580638928
TENDER_NUM 12
CRCY       840
REVID      4
REVNAME    712 Second Bar
END
```

Comment: please post a _realistic_ sample data file. do you have more than just those 7 items that you need converted to CSV format? you mention 36 lines ... but then show only 7 ... i am so very confused ... [*blush*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Do you want me to post all 36 lines?

Comment: Please do, because now we don't know if each file has info for just one user or more users info is kept there. Do all files have the same headers listed in the first column?

Comment: There 3 kinds of "files": AUTHORIZE, VOID, ADJUST. AUTHORIZE and ADJUST have the same number of lines, but slightly different header info. VOID has more header info. I will edit the original post to include examples of all three.

Comment: @Harlan - thank you for the added info. one more question - you have 3 files with TWO employee names. how do you want that handled ... or is that an error?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm looking for the final output to be one file. The EMPLOYEE column should just contain whatever information is in the EMPLOYEE field in each file. Basically one file per row. Not trying to make this more complicated than it has to be. Thanks

Comment: @Harlan - kool ... [*grin*] i note the very regular starting column of the 2nd column. is that just spaced over or is it done with tabs?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Good question! :) It's the same length as a tab, though when I look at the original file, I can move over by a single space, not a tab. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Harlan - super! [*grin*] please take a look at the Answer i just posted. it seems to work with the files you posted fairly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way to merge those text files into a CSV. it presumes the files are in a specific dir and can be loaded by matching the names OR by simply grabbing all the files.

what it does ...

- sets the source dir
- sets the file filter
- grabs all the matching files
- iterates thru the file list
- loads each file into a $Var
- uses the way that PoSh handles a collection on the LEFT side of a match
  that gives you the matching item, not the usual `[bool]`.
- builds a PSCustomObject
  it does that by matching the line with the target word, getting the 1st item in the returned array, replaces the unwanted part of the line with nothing, and finally assigns that value to the desired property.
  this is rather inefficient, but i can't think of a better way. [*blush*]
- sends the PSCO out to the `$Results` collection
- shows what is in `$Results` on the screen
- exports `$Results` to a CSV file

here's the code ...

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = 'harlan_*.txt'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filter -File

$Results = foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $Lines = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Type = ($Lines -match '^type')[0] -replace '^type\s{1,}'
        DOB = ($Lines -match '^dob')[0] -replace '^dob\s{1,}'
        Date = ($Lines -match '^date')[0] -replace '^date\s{1,}'
        Time = ($Lines -match '^time')[0] -replace '^time\s{1,}'
        Terminal = ($Lines -match '^terminal')[0] -replace '^terminal\s{1,}'
        OrgTerm = ($Lines -match '^orgterm')[0] -replace '^orgterm\s{1,}'
        Employee = ($Lines -match '^employee')[0] -replace '^employee\s{1,}'
        }
    }

# show on screen   
$Results

# save to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$SourceDir\Harlan_-_MergedFiles.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

display on screen ...

```
Type     : ADJUST
DOB      : 20200131
Date     : 20200131
Time     : 22:18:27
Terminal : 8
OrgTerm  : 8
Employee : 789 Judy Garland

Type     : AUTHORIZE
DOB      : 20200131
Date     : 20200131
Time     : 23:29:22
Terminal : 2
OrgTerm  : 
Employee : 1234 Jane Doe

Type     : VOID
DOB      : 20200131
Date     : 20200131
Time     : 21:19:42
Terminal : 3
OrgTerm  : 2
Employee : 1234 Jane Doe
```

content of the csv file ...

```
"Type","DOB","Date","Time","Terminal","OrgTerm","Employee"
"ADJUST","20200131","20200131","22:18:27","8","8","789 Judy Garland"
"AUTHORIZE","20200131","20200131","23:29:22","2","","1234 Jane Doe"
"VOID","20200131","20200131","21:19:42","3","2","1234 Jane Doe"
```

Comment: This one worked! It's a little tedious to hard code all of the headers, but I think because there are the four spaces before each header, it had to be done. I couldn't find another way to do it. I did have to modify both the `match` and the `replace`.  `TYPE = ($lines -match 'type')[0] -replace '^\s{4}type\s{1,}'`. Other than that, it seems to be working. Going to try it on a directory full of files next.

Comment: @Harlan - there is a way to handle all of them ... but it gets really obnoxious really quickly. take a look at the hidden `.PSObject` property & its sub-props. in any case, glad to know you got it working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

To capture all fields in the files without hardcoding the headers and combine them into a CSV file, the below code should do it.
Snag is that there is one line in each file that does not have a 'Header', it is just a string `{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}`.

I'm guessing that should be the Card Number, so I'm manually inserting the header `CARDNUMBER` there. If this is something else, please change that in the code.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File

$result = foreach($file in $files) {
    $obj = [PsCustomObject]@{}
    Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^(BEGIN|END)$' } | ForEach-Object {
        # There is a line without 'header' name. Is this the card number?
        if ($_ -like '{*}') {
            $name = 'CARDNUMBER'  # <-- add your own preferred header name here
            $value = $_
        }
        else {
            $name,$value = $_ -split '\s+', 2
        }
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $name -Value $value
    }
    # output the object for this file to be colected in the $result variable
    $obj
}

# output on screen
$result

#output  to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>You need to set the paths for `Get-ChildItem` and `Export-CSV` to match your own situation of course</sup>

Comment: I think the reason @Lee_Dailey & I had approaches that required manually dealing with header names is because the output spec from Harlan didn't have all the fields in it requiring some kind of select.  It's pretty cool that all of us had similar ideas!

Comment: @Steven Yes, I always kind of like questions that deal with parsing text files into something usable. For this one, I asked the OP to add full details and after that it was late.. Didn't see it again way after you and Lee had already answered, but I thought to put mine in anyway because it differs in that it doesn't hardcode the headers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly you have some files each has a single record of data delimited between the aptly positions words "BEGIN" & "END" You want each file to be translated into a single CSV file?

I think I've cooked up something worth while.  Though I'm sure it's not perfect.

```
$Select   = 'TYPE','DOB','DATE','TIME','TERMINAL','ORGTERM','EMPLOYEE'
ForEach( $InputFile in (Get-ChildItem $CurrentDirectory) )
{
    $OutputFile = $InputFile.BaseName + '.csv'
    $Table    = Get-Content $InputFile
    $TempHash = [Ordered]@{}

    ForEach( $Column in $Table )
    {
        If( $Column -notmatch '(^BEGIN$|^END$)' )
        {
            $TempArr = $Column.Split( ' ', 2, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries ) | ForEach{$_.Trim()}

            If( $Select -contains $TempArr[0] )
            {
                $TempHash.Add($TempArr[0], $TempArr[1] )
            }
        }
    }

    #Now $TempHash should have enough to create the object and export to CSV
    [PSCustomObject]$TempHash | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

A few points:

- I'm ignoring the lines BEGIN & END
- I'm manipulating each line thereafter into an array, which for the
  most part should be 2 elements.
- If the first element [0] is in the collection of fileds your looking
  for I'll add as a key/value pair to the hash.  Otherwise do nothing.
- After processing the lines Convert the object to a PSCustomObject and
  export to a CSV file.
- I only tested it on a single file I created from your question.  I wrapped up the outer loop just as pseudo code.

This works, but the output looks a little choppy, like numbers being strings and such.  That said, as a rev one I think we've got something to work with.

If misread your comment, and you want a single output CSV file the adjustment is just to declare the filename before the loop and use the append param on the Export-CSV cmdlet.  See below, though I didn't test it any further:

```
$OutputFile = 'YourOutput.csv'
$Select   = 'TYPE','DOB','DATE','TIME','TERMINAL','ORGTERM','EMPLOYEE'

ForEach( $InputFile in (Get-ChildItem $CurrentDirectory) )
{
    $Table    = Get-Content $InputFile
    $TempHash = [Ordered]@{}

    ForEach( $Column in $Table )
    {
        If( $Column -notmatch '(^BEGIN$|^END$)' )
        {
            $TempArr = $Column.Split( ' ', 2, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries ) | ForEach{$_.Trim()}

            If( $Select -contains $TempArr[0] )
            {
                $TempHash.Add($TempArr[0], $TempArr[1] )
            }
        }
    }

    #Now $TempHash should have enough to create the object and export to CSV
    [PSCustomObject]$TempHash | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
```

Sorry about the variable names, that could obviously use a refactor...

Let me know what you think.